# What software can draw boxplots?

Tags: math-software

I'm looking for a program that is capable of drawing such a picture (with all the descriptions as well):

[image: boxplot]

I would be very grateful for any suggestion.

Comment: What math software can't draw boxplots, I wonder. Pick one, and most likely it's possible. Matlab. R. Excel. Geogebra.

Comment: sorry, I meant a picture with all the descriptions as well. Thanks though!

Comment: The descriptions look like text boxes overlayed onto the image.

Comment: Export your plot from the favorite math software into an appropriate image editor and add the descriptions manually.

Comment: medcalc is useful if you want to show the individual data points as well, also for comparisons https://www.medcalc.org/manual/box_and_whisker_plot.php